# How to save a video by MediaStore on Android Q

Tags: android, mediastore, android-10.0

I write this function to insert a video file:

```kotlin
@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
private fun String.insertQ(url: Uri, bucketName: String, subDir: String): Uri? {
    return contentResolver.insert(url, contentValuesOf(
            MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME to this,
            MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE to URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromName(this),
            MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH to "$bucketName/$subDir",
            MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATE_MODIFIED to System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000
    ))
}
```

I want to download a video and output the video to the uri created by the function above. The code run with no exception, but the video has no duration time, it is 0 after query.

In this case, I can't know the duration of the video when I insert.

The google says this:

> MediaStore.MediaColumns.DURATION is read-only and cannot be mutated.

So I can't update this column manually after download.

Finally, I find this code works for updating the duration:

```kotlin
fun Uri.notifyMediaScanner() {
    application.sendBroadcast(Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE).apply {
        data = this@notifyMediaScanner.toFileUri()
    })
}
```

The things I confused is the Documention of `Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE` write this:

> Callers should migrate to inserting items directly into
> {@link MediaStore}, where they will be automatically scanned
> after each mutation.

It looks like I don't need to invoke the function `notifyMediaScanner` after download.

So, is there a right way to save a video by MediaStore?

Comment: `but the video has no duration time, it is 0 after query.` Please tell file size also.

Comment: The file size is not large, it is some short video. Size like 2MB